# Script Error Emailing

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that was developed a few years ago by my predecessor.  I was notified that individuals were receiving emails from his e-mail rather than an alias he had used.  I went in to look at the script and since then it has not been working.  Below is the error I get:

> Start         Function                    Error Message 2/8/18
>   1:55PM    onReportOrApprovalSubmit    Invalid email: undefined (line 438,
>                                               file "Trans Request Approval")

Below is line 438 of the script:

```
    GmailApp.sendEmail(row.username, 
    'Transportation Request - ' + approvedOrRejected + ' - Request ID: ' + row.rowNumber, 
    '', {htmlBody: messageDecision}); //'from': aliases[4]
```

I feel certain that the alias is the problem but it was working fine.  Then it was working but not sending the message using the alias.  Then when I go in to look at the script, stopped working all together.  I did not change anything.  All I did was look at the script.

I will be honest and admit that my scripting skills are not great, but I don't see why this stopped working.  Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From reading your post I assume that the script is still running from your predecessors' account? However, the `//` before `'from': aliases[4]` looks as if it's commenting out that parameter of the i.e. the text is an orange clour in the script editor. I believe that any small change to the script will break the trigger so adding the trigger again may get the script working.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message, the likeliest cause is that row.username doesn't have a valid email value. Please log it and see if it does have an email value in it.

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(row.username, 'Transportation Request - ' + approvedOrRejected + ' - Request ID: ' + row.rowNumber, '', {htmlBody: messageDecision}); //'from': aliases[4]
```

You can also check the correct documentation for settings aliases using GmailApp under the Advanced Parameters section for the 'from' parameter in this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)).